# Why are the verb groups in Japanese called "consonant-stem" and "vowel-stem"?

Tags: verbs, terminology

They both contain vowels and consonants. So why should 1 be called consonant and the other vowel?

Answer (score 8):

You'll understand if you just look at them romanized:

1. ### Vowel-stem verbs (一段動詞)

   ```
   　食べない　tabe-nai
   　食べます　tabe-masu
   　食べる　　tabe-ru  
   　食べれば　tabe-reba
   　食べよう　tabe-yoo
   ```

   The stem is *tabe-*, which ends with /e/, a vowel.
2. ### Consonant-stem verbs (五段動詞)

   ```
   　泳がない　oyog-anai
   　泳ぎます　oyog-imasu
   　泳ぐ　　　oyog-u
   　泳げば　　oyog-eba
   　泳ごう　　oyog-oo
   ```

   The stem is *oyog-*, which ends with /g/, a consonant.

Simple as that.

Answer (score 4):

When learning Japanese as a foreign language, "consonant-stem" (respectively "vowel-stem") verbs are called thus, because **their stem *ends* in a consonant** (resp. **vowel**), where "stem" refers to the part not changing during inflection (conjugation).

> m**i**-ru, m**i**-tai, m**i**-masu, m**i**-nai, m**i**-r-eba, m**i**-y-ou...
>
> ki**k**-u, ki**k**-i-tai, ki**k**-i-masu, ki**k**-a-nai, ki**k**-eba, ki**k**-ou...

Depending on the inflection, consonant-stem verbs change the vowel coming after the consonant in the stem. In fact, all five vowels appear, which is why in traditional Japanese grammar (where the concepts "consonant" and "vowel" aren't used) they are said to follow 五段活用 "five rank conjugation". The vowel in the vowel-stem verbs doesn't change, so they follow 一段活用 "single rank conjugation".

Note that the dichotomy consonant-stem–vowel-stem is a simplification of traditional Japanese grammar, which further divides the ("vowel-stem") "single rank conjugation" into "upper" and "lower" (and also ignores the verbs *suru* and *kuru*). (Have a look at the  table on [Wikipedia](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:%E6%B4%BB%E7%94%A8%E3%81%AE%E7%A8%AE%E9%A1%9E).)